# Jenkins Exec Format Error while cloning repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running a jenkins pipeline however it is unable to get the connect to github repo

Below is the error message

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- git@git.assembla.com:untold-universe.backend.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
> stdout:
> stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh12333381895369065263.sh-copy': Exec format error
> fatal: unable to fork

i tried to clone a public git repo it is able to retrieve the jenkinsfile from the repo but fails to checkout the codebase with below error.

> no hup cant run 'sh' exec format error.

I have configured /bin/bash as shell in my global tools configuration.

There is no error output in logs.